# LINUX : How to Install and Run XAMPP on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, installation, xampp

I'm trying to follow the steps but I can't make it work:

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

I have finished: **Step 1 and 2**

And I'm stuck at  **Step 3: Start**

**Here is a screenshot about the problems and what I did so far:**

[image: command]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't install in `/opt` you need to edit the `~Desktop/lampp/lampp` script and tell it that it's in a non-standard location. I'm just looking at that file now in my lampp test machine and you need to find all instances of `/opt/lampp` and replace them with your installation location. That file could benefit from a little variable use so you don't have to make 50+ edits all over the place.

Optionally, move `~/Desktop/lampp` to /`opt/lampp` and it'll "just work".

Comment: Hey thanks!! It works but I still have a problem, everything start outside of MySQL :(, check out the screenshot http://i52.tinypic.com/fzb0oz.png

Comment: @CIRK: You need to install myqsl. Run `sudo aptitude install mysql-client mysql-server`.

Comment: Hey I fixed it!! Thanks very much for you help!

Comment: @Giles: LAMPP includes MySQL in the bundle. You don't need to install it as a separate package.